# javascript: extract parts of a string (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

The question is simple, assume the following string:

```
var str = '<a href="aaaa">aaaaa</a><a href="bb">b\'s</a>'
```

How do you extract the value of href. I would think something like

```
var arr = str.match(/(?:href=")(\w+)/g) ;
--> ["href="aaaa", "href="bb"]
```

Of course I want

```
["aaaa", "bb"]
```

Withoug the /g it get close, but it only matches "aaaa". Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM parsing with JS is so easy.

```
var str = '<a href="aaaa">aaaaa</a><a href="bb">b\'s</a>',
    help = document.createElement('div');

helper.innerHTML = str;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(help.querySelectorAll("a[href]"), function (elem) {
    console.log(elem.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/gtdFh/

Answer (score 2):

Because Javascript doesn't have lookbehind, this may be what you want. Naturally there *will* be more elegant solutions:

```
input.match(/<[^href|/]*(href[\s]*=[\s]*")([^"]+)(?=">)/g).map(
function(x){return x.split('href')[1].replace(/[^"]+"(.*)/,'$1');
})
```

Additionally, you *may* be better off getting a HTML parsing plugin. And extracting the properties you need using that.

Cheers.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this. The solution is prone to break.

Comment: It depends, right? If you have predictable input etc it should be fine. Also he _did_ tag his question as regex, and I am not in a position to argue. Good on you for not bloody down-voting though :)

Comment: `If you have predictable input etc it should be fine.` Fair enough, but your regex is too strict that I think it is hardly useful. `Also he did tag his question as regex` It does not mean the answer *must* be regex.

Comment: Ok, fair enough buddy. 1 problem situation may be where 'href="' does not occur in a html tag at all. Any others? I can revise the answer.

Comment: I was referring to how you only consider `\w+` for a link, which I don't know whether this is what the OP actually want, since it is very restricted. As for improving the answer, you can create a detached node that contains the HTML and use DOM to pick out the anchor tags, then link in href.

Comment: I think I improved it. Arbitrary html tags with href properties should be handled. And the surrounding bracket issue is no more. Anything else? Indeed there may some redundancy in there. I _did_ say there will be more elegant solutions.